# Xcode indentation settings for Swift vs. Objective C

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a project with a large codebase, where newer modules are being added in Swift 3, but most of the code is in Objective C.  Like many projects, our Swift style uses 2 spaces for indentation.  The legacy Objective C codebase, however, uses 4 spaces.

Is there any way in Xcode 8+ to configure indentation on a per file type basis?  If not, is there a better alternative to:

1. Converting all Objective C files to use two spaces.
2. Impose the Objective C 4 space style on Swift code due to Xcode limitations.

Both of the above seem like bad ideas, but without Xcode support for per file type configuration, there seems to be no other way.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think using 4 space indentation in Swift is bad. It's the Xcode default and there are certainly popular projects like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) that use it.

Comment: You can leave it at 4 spaces for the project and use swiftformat to format (and indent) your code after every build/commit/etc. to use 2 spaces.

Comment: Obviously I can just live with 4 spaces on Swift.  It just seems silly that Xcode does not have an easy way of supporting what has become the most common Swift codeing standard without imposing it on Objective C, too.  Apple did choose Swift for use with XCode, after all.

Comment: @davidgyoung "the most common swift coding standard"... Do you have any source of this claim? Personally I've only ever seen 4 space indentation in any online resources.

Comment: 4 spaces is the standard, for ObjC and Swift. 2 spaces comes from JS devs trying their luck at Swift development. Don't let that spew over to Swift. Use 4 spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question of:

> Is there any way in Xcode 8+ to configure indentation on a per file type basis?

Yes, there is. On the `File Inspector` of each file, you can set the `Indent` type to `Spaces` or `Tab` and also the number of `spaces`.

I have attached the screenshot here:
[image]

You can select multiple file and update the settings at the same time. The settings here will overwrite what you have set in the `Preferences > Text Editing > Indentation`.

Comment: That is helpful, although less than ideal because it has to be set manually for each new Swift file.   Do you know if this is saved in the project file or in a user specific file?  E.g., is this setting shared across teammates?

Comment: Even if i change the indentation to 4 in `Preferences > Text Editing > Indentation` every new file is still at 2, how do i change it forever?